# How do I use Apache as a proxy for my Tomcat application?

Tags: apache, jsp, tomcat, ubuntu

I'm having a problem configuring Apache as a reverse proxy so that I can eliminate the port number from the URL to my Tomcat application. I've gone through several tutorials, but I always end up with the same issue: Apache seems to pass the HTML but none of the underlying programmatic parts and styling. (Sorry that's the best description I can come up with. Screenshots below to illustrate what I mean).

The following is what I see when I access Tomcat directly through port 8080:
[image: good]

But this is what I see when I forward through Apache:
[image: bad]

As many tutorials have suggested, I've enabled `mod_proxy`, `proxy_http`, `proxy_html`, and a few others, but have had no luck solving my issue. Here's my virtualhost file that Apache reads:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin XXXXX@XXX.COM
    ServerName www.compastround.com
    DocumentRoot /home/anthony/Public/

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/music.compastround.com-error.log

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/music.compastround.com-access.log combined
    ServerSignature Off

    ProxyPass /music/ http://localhost:8080/subsonic-tomcat/
    ProxyPassReverse /music/ http://localhost:8080/subsonic-tomcat/

    <Directory /home/anthony/Public/>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Options -Multiviews
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And here's Tomcat's server.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener" />
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

    <GlobalNamingResources>
        <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
                            type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
                            description="User database that can be updated and saved"
                            factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
                            pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
    </GlobalNamingResources>

    <Service name="Catalina">

        <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
                             connectionTimeout="20000"
                             URIEncoding="UTF-8"
                             redirectPort="8443" />

        <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               URIEncoding="UTF-8"
               proxyName="www.compastround.com"
               proxyPort="80" />

        <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

            <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
                <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
                             resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
            </Realm>

            <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
                        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

                <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
                             prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
                             pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

            </Host>
        </Engine>
    </Service>
</Server>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't change the context path between httpd and Tomcat - that opens up a world of possibilities for things to go wrong. They are all fixable but with a lot of work. Keep it simple and redeploy your "/subsonic-tomcat" web application under "/music". Then come back and tell us what is working and what isn't.

Comment: That was it, thanks! I didn't realize keeping the context path the same would make it so much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Mark Thomas' suggestion in the comments, I changed my virtualhost file so that the context paths are the same and my issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

my httpd-vhosts.conf::

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
ServerAdmin 974984076@qq.com
ServerName XXXX
ServerAlias localhost 
ProxyPass / balancer://cluster/ stickysession=JSESSIONID|jsessionid nofailover=Off
ProxyPassReverse / balancer://cluster/ 
ErrorLog "logs/lbtest-error.log"
CustomLog "logs/lbtest-access.log" common
<Proxy balancer://cluster>

BalancerMember ajp://XXX:XXX loadfactor=1 route=tomcat1
BalancerMember ajp://XXX:XXX loadfactor=2 route=tomcat2
</Proxy>

</VirtualHost>
```

my tomcat servel.xml

```
  <Service name="Catalina">


    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>


    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />



    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost"  jvmRoute="tomcat1">

      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">

        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">




        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />



      </Host>


      <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster" 

                 channelSendOptions="8">  

          <Manager className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager" 

                   expireSessionsOnShutdown="false" 

                   notifyListenersOnReplication="true"/>  



          <Channel className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.GroupChannel">  

            <Membership className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.McastService" 

           address="228.0.0.4"                port="45564"   

                        frequency="500" 

                        dropTime="3000"/>  

            <Receiver className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.nio.NioReceiver" 

                      address="auto" 

                      port="4000"  

                      autoBind="100" 

                      selectorTimeout="5000" 

                      maxThreads="6"/>  



            <Sender className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.ReplicationTransmitter">  

              <Transport className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.nio.PooledParallelSender" />  

            </Sender>  

            <Interceptor className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.TcpFailureDetector"/>  

            <Interceptor className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.MessageDispatch15Interceptor"/>  

         <Interceptor className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.ThroughputInterceptor"/>  

          </Channel>  

          <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.ReplicationValve" 

                 filter=""/>  

          <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteBinderValve"/>  



          <Deployer className="org.apache.catalina.ha.deploy.FarmWarDeployer" 

                    tempDir="/tmp/war-temp/" 

                    deployDir="/tmp/war-deploy/" 

                    watchDir="/tmp/war-listen/" 

                    watchEnabled="false"/>  

          <ClusterListener className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteSessionIDBinderListener"/>  

          <ClusterListener className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.ClusterSessionListener"/>  
     </Cluster>



  </Engine>
  </Service>
```